# perl grep with / on array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a data and already store on an array

array reference:

```
@intName={'ge-1/0/0', 'ge-1/0/2', 'ge-1/0/2', 'ge-1/0/2', 'ge-1/0/6'}

@vlanId={'','','101','102','';
```

@arrData:

```
set interfaces ge-1/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 10.100.200.1/24 arp 10.100.200.2 mac 00:16:d4:e7:9b:de
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 description "NodeB_Cluster/1211-3-PEG16#14"
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 101 family inet address 10.187.132.3/27 vrrp-group 1 virtual-address 10.187.132.1
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 102 family inet address 10.187.132.35/27 vrrp-group 2 virtual-address 10.187.132.33
set interfaces ge-1/0/6 description "BB_GSM_1x_1GE_#1_ae2_to_BA-JKCTO-02_ge-1/0/1"
set interfaces ge-1/0/6 gigether-options no-auto-negotiation
set interfaces ge-1/0/6 gigether-options 802.3ad ae2
```

expected result:

```
Interface Name, Vlan Id, IP Address
ge-1/0/0, '',10.100.200.1/24 
ge-1/0/2, '',''
ge-1/0/2,101,10.187.132.3/27
ge-1/0/2,102,10.187.132.35/27
ge-1/0/6,'',''
```

When I try to extract only the ip address, grep using "interface-name unit vlan-id" and then grep using "inet address", I didn't got the output for ge-1/0/6

code:

```
$totalInt=scalar(@intName)
for (my $i=0;$i<$totalInt;$i++){
foreach (@arrData){
if($_ =~ /set interfaces $intName[$i] unit $vlanId[$i]/){
if ($_ =~ /inet address/){print $_;}
}
}
```

output:

```
set interfaces ge-1/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 10.100.200.1/24 arp 10.100.200.2 mac 00:16:d4:e7:9b:de
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 101 family inet address 10.187.132.3/27 vrrp-group 1 virtual-address 10.187.132.1
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 102 family inet address 10.187.132.35/27 vrrp-group 2 virtual-address 10.187.132.33
```

how do we grep pnly ip after column address? and how to make non-result grep defined as ''?

Comment: Show the exact code you used and the output it gave.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : sorry for my mistakes, I've already add it

Comment: Your Dumper data does not look like an array. Either you have misconfigured your Dumper, or you don't have an array.
Here's a one-liner example: `$ perl -MData::Dumper -e '@x = ["abc", "def"]; print Dumper @x;'  $VAR1 = [
          'abc',
          'def'
        ];
$`

Comment: Your example is incomplete and incoherent.
What is in `@arrData` ? (Data::Dumper output should be fine).
How do you initialize `$totalInt` ?

Comment: @arrData is the data for "set interfaces.." so on. $totalInt=scalar(@intName)

Comment: No, "set interfaces.." is not an array. You need to present the exact output of `print Dumper @arrData;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Interface Name,Vlan Id,IP Address\n";

while (<DATA>) {
    my $interface = /interfaces\s+(\S+)\s+/ ? $1 : q/''/;
    my $vlanID    = /unit\s+(\S+)\s+/       ? $1 : q/''/;
    my $ip        = /address\s+(\S+)\s+/    ? $1 : q/''/;
    print "$interface,$vlanID,$ip\n";
}

__DATA__
set interfaces ge-1/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 10.100.200.1/24 arp 10.100.200.2 mac 00:16:d4:e7:9b:de
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 description "NodeB_Cluster/1211-3-PEG16#14"
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 101 family inet address 10.187.132.3/27 vrrp-group 1 virtual-address 10.187.132.1
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 102 family inet address 10.187.132.35/27 vrrp-group 2 virtual-address 10.187.132.33
set interfaces ge-1/0/6 description "BB_GSM_1x_1GE_#1_ae2_to_BA-JKCTO-02_ge-1/0/1"
set interfaces ge-1/0/6 gigether-options no-auto-negotiation
set interfaces ge-1/0/6 gigether-options 802.3ad ae2
```

Output:

```
Interface Name,Vlan Id,IP Address
ge-1/0/0,0,10.100.200.1/24
ge-1/0/2,'',''
ge-1/0/2,101,10.187.132.3/27
ge-1/0/2,102,10.187.132.35/27
ge-1/0/6,'',''
ge-1/0/6,'',''
ge-1/0/6,'',''
```