# how to grep specific string and show only specific column

Tags: perl, grep

I got an array with elements:

```
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 108 family inet address 10.187.132.227/27 vrrp-group 8 virtual-address 10.187.132.225
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 108 family inet address 10.187.132.227/27 vrrp-group 8 priority 200
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 108 family inet address 10.187.132.227/27 vrrp-group 8 accept-data
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 109 family inet address 10.187.133.3/27 vrrp-group 9 virtual-address 10.187.133.1
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 109 family inet address 10.187.133.3/27 vrrp-group 9 priority 190
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 109 family inet address 10.187.133.3/27 vrrp-group 9 accept-data
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 110 family inet address 10.187.133.35/27 vrrp-group 10 virtual-address 10.187.133.33
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 110 family inet address 10.187.133.35/27 vrrp-group 10 priority 200
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 110 family inet address 10.187.133.35/27 vrrp-group 10 accept-data
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 111 family inet address 10.187.133.67/27 vrrp-group 11 virtual-address 10.187.133.65
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 111 family inet address 10.187.133.67/27 vrrp-group 11 priority 190
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 111 family inet address 10.187.133.67/27 vrrp-group 11 accept-data
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 112 family inet address 10.187.133.99/27 vrrp-group 12 virtual-address 10.187.133.97
```

how do I grep only string between address and vrrp-group?

Comment: This was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550612/perl-grep-with-on-array/20551373#20551373).

Answer (score 1):

```
 my @array = ...

 my @strings = map {/address\s*(.*?)\s*vrrp-group/ ? $1 : ()} @array;
```

Answer (score -1):

Presuming each line is an element, `split` each element on spaces to turn it into an array, the look in the relevant array element.